# Calling getValidationErrors() with breezejs entity validation in angularjs ng-repeat causes errors

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Let say we have a simple entity level validator like this:

```
function entityIdIsValidFn(entity,context) {
    if (entity.Id1)
        return true;

    if (entity.Id2)
        return true;

    return false;

}

var entityIdValidator = new breeze.Validator("entityIdValidator", entityIdIsValidFn, {    messageTemplate: "Id1 or Id2 must be defined" });
var entityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Entity");
 entityType.validators.push(entityIdValidator);
```

Now if I try to display validation error messages in a angularjs view like this:

```
   <div ng-repeat="error in  selectedEntity.entityAspect.getValidationErrors() " class="alert alert-danger">{{error.errorMessage}}</div>
```

I get a bunch of Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! errors.

If I have validators only attached to properties validation errors will display just fine but once I attach  avalidator to an entity type I run into trouble. Anybody got an idea why this happens and consequently how to display validation error messages correctly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

While I did not get your error I had no problem reproducing one of my own. There is a Breeze bug in `getValidationErrors` (line 3839 of breeze.debug.js v.1.4.6) where it iterates over the error collection, testing the property name.

```
ve.property.name === propertyName
```

An entity-level validation error (`ve`) does not have a property and therefore the code fails with a null reference error while trying to access the undefined `property.name`.

A temporary workaround might be to patch this line with

```
ve.property && ve.property.name === propertyName
```

We've fixed it in GitHub. It will appear in the next (1.4.7) release.  Thanks for reporting it.